# I want a code for infolinks javascript that need to be run after scrolling event. ( Infolinks script on scroll )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div style=" border: 1px solid black;

    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;" id="myDIV">In my younger and more vulnerable years my 
father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my

mind ever since. <br><br> 'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'</div>

<p id="demo">oops</p>

<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {     var infolinks_pid = 2967638; var infolinks_wsid = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " ( infolinks script here ..)";

} </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQuery `$(window).scroll()` function will help you to solve your problem. If you are using JQuery, you can do like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var window_pos = $(window).scrollTop(); // Scroll position of window
 if(window_pos > 300){
  // 300px is just a number (px values)
  // you can execute a function here
}
});
```

In your javascript code, i think just add the `if` condition to check the end of scroll.